# Is it possible to make the other partial view with paging unaffected when I clicked "page 2"

Tags: c#, paging

I have 3 patial views and all have paging. they are all rendered in one page and when I move to next page on one of the partial views, the other 2 also moves to page 2.

the 3 partial views contains pagelisted tables using PageList.Mvc. the data is gathered from the individual partial views themselve using @{}.

what i expect is that when i moved to page 2 on one of the partial, the others should stay on page 1.

Comment: Yes, that sounds to be possible

Comment: please share your code

Comment: oh, i have already solved it, its possible, still thank you all